# nosetests gives different results in different directories

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose, nosetests

I have a project where I am wanting to run my code in the context of a daemon.  I am using a daemon class from here :

http://www.gavinj.net/2012/06/building-python-daemon-process.html

I wanted to run a simple test to confirm that my daemon is starting and stopping properly and a few other things.  I have that test in my test directory and my directory layout is like so:

```
mydaemon
    mydaemon
        /__init__.py
        /daemon.py
        /mydaemonrunner.py
    tests
        /test_mydaemonrunner.py
```

When I run nosetests from inside the test directory, my test passes without an issue.  However, when I run nosetests from the root mydaemon directory I get a called process error.  Here is the test that I'm passing in...

```
class test_mydaemonrunner(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        output = subprocess.check_output(["sudo","python","../mydaemon/mydaemonrunner.py","start",stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        m = re.match("started with pid (\d+)", output)
        if m:
            self.process_pid = m(1)
        else:
            print "Test Setup was not successful"
```

For the record, the error that is being raised is a CalledProcessError.

So, my question is:

What could cause nosetests to fail when running in the root directory of my project but to pass when run in the tests directory?  And is there a preferred directory structure that will minimize these sorts of issues?

Comment: Ugh, ok sorry this was a stupid question and indeed the CalledProcessError was relevant.  The issue had to do with my relative referencing of the location in the subprocess call.  Once I replaced the ../ with the full path the error went away...